# What is the best way to get kernel 3.2 on Debian 6?

Tags: linux, debian, hyper-v, kernel

I'm using Hyper-V as hypervisor and there is a need to use Debian 6 in production on it, but as I know it's not supported. I want to use kernel 3.2 with integrated linux integration components. What is the best way to get it working safe and stable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to use the Debian `backports` repository, more info [here](http://backports-master.debian.org/Instructions/). It contains recent kernels.